# pip install iconsdk: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, egg

I've set up a virtualevn, updated everything I could possibly find to up date per stackover flow submissions. I'm trying to use a blockchain sdk and when I go to: `pip3 install iconsdk` I get:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

I've checked and updated everything under `pip list` (example, `pip install --upgrade ez-setup`). List below:

(iconex) C:\Users\admin\Desktop\icon_ex>pip list
Package    Version

---

ez-setup   0.9
pip        18.1
pkgconfig  1.4.0
setuptools 40.4.3
wheel      0.32.2

When I run pip3 install iconsdk my logs show:

> (iconex) C:\Users\admin\Desktop\icon_ex>pip3 install iconsdk
>   Collecting iconsdk   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/3d/41afe66527ff9800250ed040fb210c43cb3e1715d9e57f89f2423d891309/iconsdk-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting eth-keyfile==0.5.1 (from iconsdk)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/a5/3615d100b62fbf20fe5d5c0d1d4d7326eac861d260b0cd2a36af2bf8ccb1/eth_keyfile-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting secp256k1==0.13.2 (from iconsdk)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/62/d7bf3829e126e517e253d2e22a63511c54bbaac34d7ddea316cde040fc49/secp256k1-0.13.2.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       'pkg-config' is required to install this package. Please see the README for details.
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> ```
>
> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7q5b2ud\secp256k1\

How can I fix this?

Btw, a lot of solutions started with "sudo", which isn't recognized when I use that i the command.

Again, I'm very new to programming so if I've left off anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps.cmd -> change path to your folder(where the setup.py is) -> try: "python setup.py build". Also, did you unzip the folder? If not, you should and try again.